# Solution for system of Law of cosines?

Tags: systems-of-equations, triangles

Imagine a setup like this:

[image]

a b c are sides of a triangle,O is an arbitary point in 3D space,x y z are lines bewteen O and the vertex of the triangle, $\alpha$ $\beta$ $\gamma$ are angles between x y z.

From Law of cosines we have the following equations

$\frac{x^2 + y^2 -a^2}{2xy}=cos(\alpha)$

$\frac{y^2 + z^2 -b^2}{2yz}=cos(\beta)$

$\frac{z^2 + x^2 -c^2}{2zx}=cos(\gamma)$

Can we solve $x, y, z$ in terms of $a, b, c$ and  $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ ?

Edit: Here is a bit of more support information look at the 3 torus intersecting each other. The red one will be the x y which satisfy equation one, the green for equation two, blue for equation three. Where three color meets altogether is the answer we looking for. There are two on this side of the triangle and there is two mirror image on the other side. So out of 8 possible solutions, we should have two left. Yet still, how do we express them in mathematical terms.

[image]

Comment: You can do the following: solve the first equation for $y$ and plug this in the second one,solve this new equation for $z$ and plug this in the last equation and try to solve this new equation for $x$.

Comment: this question is related to the "Law of cosines"

Comment: Nice approach Rabie. There is an easy solution if $\alpha$ and others are cosines of angels related to a triangle. I wonder if there is a general solution - not imaginary roots.

Comment: i have this triangle in mind https://ibb.co/iOOc3c

Comment: where $\alpha =\cos \left( {{\phi }_{1}} \right),\beta =\cos \left( {{\phi }_{2}} \right),\gamma =\cos \left( {{\phi }_{3}} \right)$ and ${{\phi }_{1}}+{{\phi }_{2}}+{{\phi }_{3}}=2\pi $

Comment: You can not eliminate any of the  x y or z from the equations above, so  Gauss elimination doesnt really work.subsitude α=cos(ϕ1),β=cos(ϕ2),γ=cos(ϕ3) is fine you can even assume all variables are positive,but ϕ1+ϕ2+ϕ3=2π is no guarantee it's should be between 0~2π.And yes a b c will forms a triangle.

Comment: if you try to push one variable to the other side each time you will end up have a +- of a square root and each time you substitude this to the next equation and sovle you will have a +-of square root with nested squares.And you need to do this 3 times so at the end there will be 8 possible solutions and the expression get crazy large to describe.

Comment: ╮（╯＿╰）╭。。。。。。。。。。。。。。。