# Solve system of 2nd order equations with 3 variables

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

$x^2 + y^2 -2xycos(\alpha)-a^2=0$

$y^2 + z^2 -2yzcos(\beta)-b^2=0$

$z^2 + x^2 -2zxcos(\gamma)-c^2=0$

Is there a way to solve this system of equation,yet keep the final expression to some extend short and neat.There could be 8 sets of x y z and only 2 of them are correct.(only real and positive root are considered),How to vadidate them?

Comment: I’m having trouble seeing how this is different from [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2758699/265466).

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be a little simpler than you think. Note that the first three terms on the left represent the distance between two vectors of length $x$ and $y$ with an angle $\alpha$ between them.
$$x^2+y^2-2xy\cos(\alpha)=|\vec{x}-\vec{y}|^2$$
Thus, given the constants, we geometrically conclude that if a solution exists for $x$, $y$ and $z$ then the absolute values of each must form a triangle. Thus, there are $2^3=8$ for a valid set of constants. The constants themselves must satisfy that the sum of the angle is a multiple of $\pi$ and that $a$, $b$ and $c$ also form a triangle.

Comment: could you elaboate a bit further and attempt to get a explicit expression for one of the variables

Comment: This system of equations in fact arises from applying the Law Of Cosines to the faces of an unknown tetrahedron, so I expect that the poster already knows this. See [his previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2758699/265466).

Comment: It is pretty much the same question,yet still lack of answer offering an explict solution.The only solution I can find is quite lenghy and it is implicit(still got variable inside final solution).I need a better way to solve this.

Comment: @shadow_wxh: don't expect an easy solution for a nonlinear problem with 8 solutions, leading to an octic polynomial.